# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scapy.all'; 'scapy' is not a package

Tags: python, scapy

Пишу DHCP снифер с помощью Scapy на Python.Но при запуске кода вылезает ошибка в первой строке

```
File "D:\failes\все\scripts\scapy.py", line 1, in <module>
    from scapy.all import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scapy.all'; 'scapy' is not a package
```

сам код импортов -

```
from scapy.all import *
```

как это исправить?

Comment: установить scapy ?

Comment: не помогает, устанавливал, переустанавливал, не помогло

Comment: а какая версия ?

Comment: У меня стоит 2.4.5 версия Scapy

Comment: а устанавливали как в доках  https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#windows ?

Comment: устанавливал, не помогло

Comment: Не называйте файлы именами пакетов. Python нашел Ваш файл, его и пытается импортировать.

Comment: Тоже не помогло

Comment: Что именно не помогло? Переименуйте свой файл хотя бы в myscapy.py и запустите заново. И почистите папку `__pycache__`

Comment: Я назвал файл scapyprogram, ошибка не пропала

Comment: папку `__pycache__` тоже почистили?

Comment: Большое спасибо, после очистки папки `__pycache__` все заработало!

Answer (score 0):

Я понимаю, что данный ответ уже устарел. Но, возможно, кому-то будет полезен.

Можно попробовать:

```
import scapy.all as sc
```

Тогда, перед тем, как обратиться к какому-либо модулю, нужно будет указывать префикс. То есть, для примера:

```
sc.IP(dst="192.168.1.1")
```

Но, думаю, что это, все же, не совсем верный путь. Гораздо правильнее будет импортировать именно тот модуль, который нужен:

```
from scapy.layers.inet import TCP_client, IP
```